# Cloud Architecture On Azure for Internet of Things

Tags: azure, tcp, embedded, cloud, azureservicebus

I'm working on a server architecture for sending/receiving messages from remote embedded devices, which will be hosted on Windows Azure. The front-facing servers are going to be maintaining persistent TCP connections with these devices, and I need a way to communicate with them on the backend.

Problem facts:

- Devices: ~10,000
- Frequency of messages device is sending up to servers: 1/min
- Frequency of messages originating server side (e.g. from user actions, scheduled triggers, etc.): 100/day
- Average size of message payload: 64 bytes

**Upward communication**

The devices send up messages very frequently (sensor readings). The constraints for that data are not very strong, due to the fact that we can aggregate/insert those sensor readings in a batched manner, and that they don't require in-order guarantees. I think the best way of handling them is to put them in a Storage Queue, and have a worker process poll the queue at intervals and dump that data. Of course, I'll have to be careful about making sure the worker process does this frequently enough so that the queue doesn't infinitely back up. The max batch size of Azure Storage Queues is 32, but I'm thinking of potentially pulling in more than that: something like publishing to the data store every 1,000 readings or 30 seconds, whichever comes first.

**Downward communication**

The server sends down updates and notifications much less frequently. This is a slightly harder problem, as I can see two viable paradigms here (with some blending in between). Could either:

1. Create a Service Bus Queue for each device (or one queue with thousands of subscriptions - limit is for number of queues is 10,000)
2. Have a state table housed in a DB that contains the latest "state" of a specific message type that the devices will get sent to them

With option 1, the application server simply enqueues a message in a fire-and-forget manner. On the front-end servers, however, there's quite a bit of things that have to happen. Concerns I can see include:

- Monitoring 10k queues (or many subscriptions off of a queue - the
  Azure SDK apparently reuses connections for subscriptions to the same
  queue)
- Connection Management

  - Should no longer monitor a queue if device disconnects.
  - Need to expire messages if device is disconnected for an extended period of time (so that queue isn't backed up)
  - Need to enable some type of "refresh" mechanism to update device's complete state when it goes back online

The good news is that service bus queues are durable, and with sessions can arrange messages to come in a FIFO manner.

With option 2, the DB would house a table that would maintain state for all of the devices. This table would be checked periodically by the front-facing servers (every few seconds or so) for state changes written to it by the application server. The front-facing servers would then dispatch to the devices. This removes the requirement for queueing of FIFO, the reasoning being that this message contains the latest state, and doesn't have to compete with other messages destined for the same device. The message is ephemeral: if it fails, then it will be resent when the device reconnects and requests to be refreshed, or at the next check interval of the front-facing server.

In this scenario, the need for queues seems to be removed, but the DB becomes the bottleneck here, and I fear it's not as scalable.

These are both viable approaches, and I feel this question is already becoming too large (although I can provide more descriptions if necessary). Just wanted to get a feel for what's possible, what's usually done, if there's something fundamental I'm missing, and what things in the cloud can I take advantage of to not reinvent the wheel.

Comment: For incoming data, consider initially storing these data into Storage Tables - these can support a very high throughput. Process the data by worker roles asynchronously (you had this planned already, I believe), perhaps utilizing queues to parallelize this as much as possible. For outgoing data, look at Notificaton Hubs. You'll have to figure out how to feed it and remove your DB as a bottleneck, but it can manage massive numbers of connections.

Comment: @Jaxidian Let me make sure I understand what you're saying. If I store incoming data in Storage Tables, I'd probably make the ParitionKey = DeviceId and RowKey = TimeStamp. I'd have to maintain some state about the last time processed, and then query to get the new rows since then. I'd do this over each device, taking the batch since the last query and queue that batch up onto a queue as a single insert. Worker processes would then dequeue and insert those batches into the data store (which is a DB).

Comment: @Jaxidian For notification hubs, all of the research I'm doing on it suggests it's for mobile only. Also, it looks like there are situations where messages sent down would have to have FIFO semantics, or the devices would need to store timestamps for message types and throw out anything older than what they currently have. Not sure how notification hubs deal with this. And lastly, I can't find any documentation/SLA on timeliness guarantees for messages it sends out.

Answer (score 0):

If you can identify the device (may be device id/IMEI/Mac address) by the the message it sends then you can reduce the number of queues from 10,000 to 1 queue and not have 10000 subscriptions too. This could also help you in the downward communication as you will be able to identify the device and send the message to the appropriate socket.

As you mentioned the connections last longer you could deliver the command to the device that is connected and decide what to do with the commands to the device that are not connected.

Hope it helps